# How to find the url using the referer and the href in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, url, href

Suppose I have

```
window_location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
href = '/users/48465/jader-dias'
```

I want to obtain

```
link = 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/48465/jader-dias'
```

How do I do it in Python?

It have to work just as it works in the browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urljoin('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask',
...                  '/users/48465/jader-dias')
'http://stackoverflow.com/users/48465/jader-dias'
```

From the doc page of [urlparse.urljoin](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

> urlparse.urljoin(base, url[,
>   allow_fragments])
>
> Construct a full (“absolute”) URL by combining a “base URL” (base) with
>   another URL (url). Informally, this
>   uses components of the base URL, in
>   particular the addressing scheme, the
>   network location and (part of) the
>   path, to provide missing components in
>   the relative URL.
>
> If url is an absolute URL (that is,
>   starting with // or scheme://), the
>   url‘s host name and/or scheme will be
>   present in the result.